# Execute the linq queryusing Where clause from string

Tags: string, linq, c#-4.0, datatable, where-clause

Hi guys I need to use linq for querying a datatable in C#.

My scenario is that i need to filter the data in a datatable using Linq.

If single condition means my query is working using the following query,

> EnumerableRowCollection query = from contact in
>   dtContacts.AsEnumerable()
>    where contact["FirstName"].ToString().StartsWith(SearchText) select contact;

It displays the required data and working good. In case of multiple conditions means i **need to add the && operator dynamically and add the condition inside the query** because the filtering may change dynamically.

after getting  the conditions in a string i get like this,

> contact[FirstName].ToString().ToLower().Contains(Mani.ToLower()) &&
>   contact[LastName].ToString().ToLower().Startswith(S.ToLower()) &&
>   contact[EmailAddress].ToString().ToLower().Contains(mani.ToLower())

and store it in  a variable **queryString**

now i need to execute the linq query from a string

> EnumerableRowCollection query = from contact in
>   dtContacts.AsEnumerable() where **queryString** select contact;

Kindly give me a solution to **execute the where clause from string inside the linq query**

Comment: if all criteria in the where clause will be appended using AND [ **&&** ] operator only (not OR [ **||** ]), you can use extension method chain syntax instead to add criteria dynamically

Comment: Yeah i also think of that, but as i conditions fields are different and many(FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, PhoneNUmbers) and also the searching types are many(Contains, Startswith, equals) with user entered keyword. I need to satisfy all the conditions and display the result. For that i would like to store the where clause in a string variable and execute it in the query as like in SQL. Is there any possible way to execute Linq query with where clause is in string. Kindly tell me a solution for this.

Comment: I think part of your application that able to build such a where clause string must be able do build the where clause as linq or extension method instead of string. Anyway I'm quite sure you need to do it with different approach, I still think it is impossible to execute string in LINQ's where clause

Comment: LINQ is strongly typed objects, SQL is not, it is plain string. So you can't compare LINQ with SQL.

Comment: For your information i would like you to see this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx. I need exactly like this. See there he is passing where clause in string

Comment: Then you can use Scott Gu's library. He build his own library to parse plain string and transform it to LINQ expression. That's a great job. Such a feature is not available in official .NET framework as far as I know. Thats why I said impossible, I meant without going through pain of building library to parse string to linq. Different story if somebody else did the job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is impossible to execute LINQ's where clause from string just like that. Since you want to add only **&&** criteria in where clause, you can use extension method chain style to add criteria dynamically this way :

```
EnumerableRowCollection query = from contact in dtContacts.AsEnumerable() where contact["FirstName"].ToString().StartsWith(SearchText) select contact;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mani))
{
    query = query.Where(contact => contact[LastName].ToString().ToLower().Startswith(S.ToLower()))
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(S))
{
    query = query.Where(contact => contact[LastName].ToString().ToLower().Startswith(S.ToLower()))
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mani))
{
    query = query.Where(contact => contact[EmailAddress].ToString().ToLower().Contains(mani.ToLower()))
}
```

Or the same can be achieved with linq syntax, for example :

```
EnumerableRowCollection query = from contact in dtContacts.AsEnumerable() where contact["FirstName"].ToString().StartsWith(SearchText) select contact;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mani))
{
    query = select contact from query where contact[LastName].ToString().ToLower().Startswith(S.ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts, har07. As i told all the data are dynamic so i cant parse exactly as you said in the answer. Also it is mandatory that i need to satisfy the conditions(which may differ due to situations). So i need a solution to execute the query with where clause which is given from string.